# Looking for books in the same style as Hans Kellerer 2004, Knapsack Problems

Tags: optimization, reference-request, knapsack, books

I really enjoyed reading Hans Kellerer, David Pisinger, Ulrich Pferschy 2004 book Knapsack Problems. Can anybody recommend books in a similar style, about some other classes of problems / optimisation?

Comment: welcome! can you give us more details on the "style" you like, is it because of the many applications, because of the precise math, since it is a discrete optimization problem, or because it is algorithmic? what is it precisely that you like about the book?

Comment: Yes, I liked all of those things about the book!

Comment: I also liked it because it is mostly easy to follow, but I guess that is subjective.

Comment: Although it is discrete optimisation, I like how the algorithms often rely on linear relaxations of one form or another.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I waited some time but apparently no easy answer here. Thanks for providing some more hints in the comments to your question. One specialty about the knapsack book is: it is a **monograph**, that is, written by the same author(s). There are only few other books about a particular combinatorial optimization problem, with theory and algorithmic components, and precise in the mathematics, and the "LPs are used" portion.

A brilliant example is [In Pursuit of the Traveling Salesman - Mathematics at the Limits of Computation](https://www.amazon.de/Pursuit-Traveling-Salesman-William-Cook/dp/0691152705) by Bill Cook.

Often, books are **collections**, that is, they are edited by a small number of researchers, but the single chapters are written by different people, and thus usually differ in style and presentation; usually, there is not much coherence in terms of cross references among chapters etc.

One example is the area of vehicle routing, with books like [The Vehicle Routing Problem](https://www.amazon.de/Vehicle-Routing-Problem-Challenges-Operations/dp/0387777776) by Golden et al., or [Vehicle Routing: Problems, Methods, and Applications](https://www.amazon.de/Vehicle-Routing-Problems-Applications-Optimization/dp/1611973589) by Toth and Vigo.